Why aren't all Major scale chords major?
This questions seems easy but it's hard for me to come up with an answer.
I suppose it is because of the whole step and half step pattern. But then the follow up questions would be: why?

The word "major" means different things in different contexts. By definition

a major scale is the interval pattern WWHWWWH (W = whole, H = half).
a major chord  (in root position) is the interval pattern M3m3.

Chords (in root position) derived from the major scale comprise a starting pitch, then two "skip" pitches (i.e., every other note) within the scale. This will result in different interval patterns for various chords.
Consider that from one (root position) chord tone to the next comprises two W/H steps from the scale. So a chord based on the scale's tonic would have the interval pattern (WW)(HW), or M3m3 — i.e., a major chord.
But a chord built on the second scale degree will have the interval pattern (WH)(WW), or m3M3, which constitutes a minor chord.
The complete list of root-position triad chord-qualities embedded in the major scale, ordered by scale degree, is: M(ajor), m(inor), m, M, M, m, d(iminished).
By contract, the whole-tone scale contains only augmented chords, because the scale contains only one type of interval (i.e., whole tones, of course). Similarly the diminished scales, which alternate whole and half steps, contain only diminished chords.
See also:

Do the notes of triads created from key signatures stay within that signature
Chord pattern formula for constructing chords in a given major or minor key
Triads derived from the different types of minor scales
What are the formulas for chord qualities relative to natural minor?


In practice (for writing music), has there been any use of whole-tone scale and diminished scale?  Maybe older periods of Western music, or non-Western music?  I cannot recall any.

@GratefulDisciple Debussy, for example, used the whole-tone scale. The diminished scale was used by a variety of 20th-century composers.

Wow you're right, a lot more prevalent than I imagined what to be merely theoretical construct; even Chopin uses it if only for 2 measures (doesn't really qualify to be a scale IMO).  I got to play more Debussy.

@Aaron Thank you for the answer. I have a follow up questino because I don't quite get it yet: "But a chord built on the second scale degree will have the interval pattern (WH)(WW), or m3M3, which constitutes a minor chord."
--> Who defines what pitches are part of the chord or rather how many steps are needed to form the triad chord?
For example, a triad built on D in the Cmaj scale: You start on D and move up 4 semitones, which lands you on F# (not part of the Cmaj scale). But now I could just move up a half step to G instead of F for the "third" of the D triad. Why move down to F instead?

@MusicQuestions7 I'm not sure I understand your question, but G is a fourth above D, so by definition not part of a triad. Triads are defined as comprising minor and/or major thirds. As mentioned in my answer, another way to think of triads is by using every other note in the scale. D to G would skip two notes, not just one.

@Aaron Thank you very much for the reply. I mean what sets the rule that a triad has to be made of third intervals? Is that just how it is and there's no question to ask. I've heard this every other pitch to form a triad explanation multiple times but it seems like a simplification and there's actually a more sophisticated reason. Maybe I'm wrong and there's not.

@MusicQuestions7 Take a look at this answer to Why are thirds used to construct chords?.

@Aaron Wow, thank you for the fast reply. That link cleared up some things. I came up with my own answer based on the replies here and was wondering if it is correct:
"Major scale and major chord are two distinct things that share the term: major. The major scale is defined by a major tonic chord and follows the major scale step pattern. To construct chords, one has to use pitches that are part of the scale. The distances between the pitches of a triad chord have to be either major and minor third intervals because they are the most musically consonant intervals."
Hopefully correct?

@MusicQuestions7 Mostly. I would not say that the major scale is defined by the major tonic chord, just that it follows the major scale patter. The fact of a major tonic chord follows from that. Also, the distances between the pitches of a root position triad have to be either major or minor thirds. However, thirds are not the most musically consonant (octaves and fifths are).

@Aaron Thank you very much again! I have a hard time grasping it fully then, sorry. How can I put all of the info into a few sentences for me to remember?

@MusicQuestions7 The two bullet points in my post sum it up. A third point would be that the pattern of chords within a major scale are Maj, Min, Min, Maj, Maj, Min, Dim.

Thanks for your patient with me ;-). I guess the key point is that the term major simply refers to different things depending on context? The chords in a major scale are not exclusively major because the term major has a different meaning when it refers to a scale. Did I get that right?

That's right. "Major" and "minor" mean different things in different contexts, particularly with chords and scales.

@Aaron Thank you!

Why aren't all Major scale chords major?
To be very succinct: because when the chords need to be formed with only the notes of that major scale, several of the resulting chords are necessarily not a major chord.  (This presupposes the usual rules for calling a scale "major" and a chord "major", which are already covered by the definitions in @Aaron's answer.)
Let's pick the C major scale.  The tonic chord (root=C) is major because C+E+G fits the intervals needed for a major chord.  The chord with the root of D is minor because D+F+A fits the intervals needed for a minor chord, which by definition is not a major chord.  It is that simple.

Follow up question [rephrased from your comment]:

Why do we use certain intervals when others are possible? In the C major scale, let's build a triad on A. You'd go up 3 semitones to land on C and then 4 to land on E, making the A minor triad (A C E).

But why go up 3 semitones from A and not 2 semitones, which lands us on B, which is still part of the C major scale?
Or why go up 4 semitones from C to E, instead of 2 semitones to land on D?

So the question: why is there a necessity for using major / minor thirds exclusively to build the triad?

Answer: Because if you want a triad, by definition it "consists of three notes stacked in consecutive thirds" (see here).
The two chords you suggested above as alternatives (which still use notes from the major scale exclusively) would not be triads anymore:

A B E is called Asus2 chord (a suspended second chord, not a triad)
A C D is called ???? (rarely used; there's no name for it that I know of)

If you then ask: why prioritize triads?  Answer: because we are doing Western music .  See @phoog's answer for the history of the development triads in Western music from counterpoint to functional harmony where triads play a major role.  When triads are functioning in Western harmony, the upper note of a major/minor triad has to be a perfect 5th (which will be a note on the scale) with the addition of a note somewhere in the middle of that perfect 5th interval, which will be either 3 or 4 semitones from the root.

The thing that I'm getting hung up on is "why do we use certain intervals when others are possible?". For example, in the Cmaj scale we: Let's build a triad on A. You'd go up 3 semitones to land on C and then 4 to land on E. A C E is the Amin triad. But why go up 3 semitones from A and not 2? 2 semitones lands us on B, which is still part of the Cmaj scale. Or conversely, why go up 4 from C and not 2 to land on D instead of E. Why is there a necessity for using major / minor thirds exclusively?

@MusicQuestions7 I think Aaron has answered your question in the comment.  My answer is in the edited answer.

Thank you for the reply and elaborate answer. I'm on the verge of understanding it now. So, basically to sum it up:
--Major scales have triads that are not major because the term "major" means different things depending on the context. Triads are built using third intervals because the third interval is the defining characteristic of a triad.--
Did I get this right?

@MusicQuestions7 I think so.  "Major" is just a name, but there is a certain philosophy and a "trail of preference decisions" in the history of Western music that promote the use of certain chords above others.  "triad" is just a theoretical construct to conceptualize this preference.  You will also notice that in the heyday of "purer" tonal harmony of the 18th century, the I IV V major chords are more used than the ii, iii, and vi minor chords.  While the vii diminished chord is very rarely used.

Thank you again!

Other answers have explained perfectly the why, as in why do the major scale notes form non-major chords?, but I'll try to answer why as in why are there non-major chords in the major scale?
And the answer to that is because chords have functions in the scale. Very simplified: the first degree is the tonic, functions as "home", gives a feeling of "being at rest"; the fifth(1) is the dominant, which wants to resolve to the tonic; the fourth and second are subdominants, which usually precede the dominant; etc.
This means that a key/scale(2) being major signifies that it consists of various types of chords, not only major ones, to "fulfill" each function. The first chord is major, giving the sense of home; the seventh chord over the fifth degree forms a dominant seventh chord, giving the sense of tension needing resolution; etc.
And you might be asking why, as in why is the first degree "home"?. And the answer to that is that that is the very definition of a key. Why do some chords feel they need to resolve?, and why do some note movements "feel good" or "consonant" and others don't?
There is no "mathematical" answer to these questions. In western societies we are so used to tonal music that it really feels natural to us, and some propose that this is only a cultural aspect, but others say it's related to the very nature of sound (see Schoenberg's writings on harmony).
For a better understanding of harmony as applied to classical music mostly, I recommend Walter Piston's Harmony. As for the aesthetics of music, I recommend Fubini's History of music aesthetics.

(1): and usually the seventh as well, in major and harmonic minor scales
(2): I know that scale and key aren't the same thing, but OP was referring to a key rather than a scale, so I used them interchangeably.

I fee like this is what the OP's question actually is about. May I add that  in music, like everywhere else in life, there is no single emotion (joy) without its counterpart (sadness) appearing once in a while - it goes with our nature. Think of an upbeat-ending movie: it still has some tension or conflict in it - otherwise it would be boring. It's just that it resolves into something joyful - just like chords in music do

There's nothing particularly wrong with the existing answers, but I find the historical explanation to be the easiest to grasp:
First, you have the diatonic scale; the "white" notes on the keyboard.  The major scale can be obtained from these notes by establishing C as the "home" note.
To describe the intervals between pitches in the scale, we settled on ordinal numbers: second, third, fourth, fifth, etc.  Because of medieval counting conventions, we count inclusively: the ordinal that identifies the second pitch above or below is third.  For example, a third above F is A, and a third below F is D.
If you look at all the thirds in a diatonic scale, there are two sizes:

A-C: three semitones
B-D: three semitones
C-E: four semitones
D-F: three semitones
E-G: three semitones
F-A: four semitones
G-B: four semitones

These came to be known as "bigger" and "smaller" thirds at a time when Latin was still in use as the international language of western Europe; the Latin words for "bigger" and "smaller" are "major" and "minor."  (While I and J were still considered different forms of the same letter, the convention of using I for the vowel sound and J for the semivowel or consonant also became fairly well established.)
Chordal harmony also arose.  At first, the only stable consonance other than the octave was the perfect fifth.  Eventually, chords that included the note roughly in the middle of the fifth, the major or minor third, were also treated as stable.  As chords became more of a first-class concept in music theory, it became convenient to differentiate them by the quality of the third, major or minor.  This leads to the answer to your question:

I suppose it is because of the whole step and half step pattern. But then the follow up questions would be: why?

Because of the theoretical contributions of Jean-Philippe Rameau, we presently consider that there are seven triads built on the diatonic scale, one for each pitch.  To build the triad, you add to each pitch (known as the "root" of the chord) the pitches a third and a fifth above the root.  Since we're looking only at the chords that exist within the major scale, we can again use the white notes of the keyboard and C major:

C-E-G: major third, perfect fifth: major triad
D-F-A: minor third, perfect fifth: minor triad
E-G-B: minor third, perfect fifth: minor triad
F-A-C: major third, perfect fifth: major triad
G-B-D: major third, perfect fifth: major triad
A-C-E: minor third, perfect fifth: minor triad
B-D-F: minor third, diminished fifth: diminished triad


Scales are pitch-ordered collections (half-step and whole-step skips in general) of notes. It's somewhat analogous to ordering letters in an alphabet or futhark. Pairs of notes are called intervals (with names associated but not identical to the position of the pair in a major or minor scale.)
Chords are collections of 3 or more notes; they exist independently of any scale. The notes C, E, and G, make a C-major chord no matter where the notes appear on any scale. The earliest writings I have seen define a major chord as three notes with frequency ratios of 4:5:6 (approximately); they define a minor chord as three notes having ratios of 10:12:15. (These are the reciprocals of those of the major scale.)
Musically, any chord (major or minor or other) may appear in any key. Chords derive their musical meaning through their relationship to a key. Keys may have scales abstracted from them, but scales do not define keys per se.

A major chord and a major scale are fundamentally different things.
A major scale as it is defined is an 8-note scale each note having its own letter name and the semi-tones being between the third and fourth scale degrees and the seventh and eighth.
Conversely, a major chord is a set of three notes a set interval apart (root—major third—perfect fifth). Whenever you have these three notes in these specific intervals you have a major chord. These intervals have nothing specifically to do with the key you are in. 

@phoog There is a tradition in music to write the word Major with a capital M and the word minor with a lowercase m. I may be old-fashioned but it is a tradition I keep to

I think you'll find that this tradition is not as widespread nor as long standing as you think.  Do you know of a reputable publication the does this or style guide that calls for doing it?  I just had a quick look at a couple of articles from The Musical Times, for example, and they don't.  It's done in German, though with the letter names of the notes rather than with "Dur" and "Moll," and you'll see, in catalogues and the like,  G for G major and g for G minor, but not generally in English outside of abbreviations.

The defining factor for scales is the third note.
If that is a major third above the root, then it's a major. If it's a minor third above the root, then it's a minor.

Short version: Because a major third is four semitones and a fifth is seven semitones, not eight. 4 and 7 are coprime numbers.
Long version: C major chord consists of C, E and G. There's a major third from C to E, and to complete the fifth from C to G, a minor third from E to G.
If you want to build an E something chord out of the tones that can be found in the scale of C major, you will use E, G and B. (Jumping by thirds on the scale. G# isn't part of it.)
E to B is a fifth. That's good.
E to G is still the same minor third it was a moment ago. Thus, this chord inevitably must be E minor.

Technically, the fifth grade doesn't implicitly make a chord as "non" major or minor. An augmented triad can still be considered a major chord, just like a diminished one could be seen as a minor, so what really matters is the third grade to begin with.

@musicamante The chord you can make out of tones from the scale of C major isn't C+, it's C.

I agree, but that's not the point. The first aspect that may define a chord as major or minor is the third degree (or, to some level, the presence and relevance of a "third" above the fundamental). And even though it's common to define triads (and more extended chords) based on relative intervals, the convention is always based on the distance from the fundamental, with decreasing "relevance" of what follows to define the chord character. That's also why it's possible (and not uncommon) to have relatively important chords that only contain the third other than the fundamental.

@musicamante you can definite "major chord" and "minor chord" to mean "any chord with a major (or minor) third" respectively, but that is not how these terms are in fact used.  Both chords comprise by definition a third of the indicated quality and a perfect fifth.  If you call an augmented triad "major" or a diminished triad "minor" without explicitly establishing the nonstandard definition you're proposing, you will invite corrections and/or mislead the people you're trying to communicate with.
